# Do conductor fill and continual usage wire ampacity derate stack?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

In California, NEC calls to size the conductor for 125% of the load for continuous use devices.

Thus, for example, a 40A continuous load should use conductors rated for 50A. (40 * 1.25) = 50

If this conductor is going to be in a conduit holding six current-carrying conductors, NEC calls to derate the ampacity rating of the conductor to 80% of its normal value. (Assume the conduit fill percentage is fine)

Do these stack? Or is it the greater derate (these two are coincidentally the same)? Or something else?

For example, would a 40A continuous load device, served by conduit holding six current-carrying conductors need to use wiring rated for 63A such as #6 THWN?
(40 * 1.25 / 0.8) = 62.5

Comment: I can confirm your math

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they stack.

The load determines the ampacity needed. This includes a continuous load 80% factor, if appropriate.

Once you have the required ampacity, 310.15(A) through (F) determine the derating for  the ampacity that the conductor can provide.

That's why they stack. They're on two different parts of the problem. The continuous load part is on the consumer side of the math, and the multiple conductor part is on the provider side of the math.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes they do stack, but don't make the common errors here.

First, I'm going to use an example that is inherently extremely stupid.  No one with experience would ever wire it this way.  This is just an example and I'll touch on how to do it right at the end.

Let's suppose you are an Uber house which upgraded to 400A service simply to have 200A to throw into EV charging.  You have three electric large SUVs that drive 250 miles a day, and charge only 10 hours, so you need a big "50A" (40A actual x 125% for continuous load) EV charger x 3. Note the EVSE provides this derate internally and is configured/commissioned to breaker trip value. Do not apply the derate a second time. For some weird reason, you are snubbing Share2 power sharing tech, and want 3 separate circuits *in copper* with 3 disconnects, instead of one Al feeder to a local subpanel. Just bear with me, it's an example.

So you have three EVSEs, and that's six Current Carrying Conductors (neutral doesn't count in 120/240V circuits).  As such, under 310.15(B)(3)(a) you derate 80%.

You bought THWN wire. But that is not made; you actually got THHN/THWN-2 dual-listed. Both those listing give 90°C thermal rating.   #6 copper is 75 amps at 90C.  So your 80% derate knocks you down to 60A.

So you're good 2 go, and could even kick it up to "60A" charging (48A actual).

Why did I say 3 circuits? To make the "6 current carrying conductors" example work. In a 120/240V split-phase circuit, **neutral does not count** as a CCC for the 310.15(B)(3)(a) derate, as discussed therein (it only carries differential current; any current on neutral means *less* current on a hot. Heat is the square of current, so any imbalance means *less* actual heat.

### How would that example be done properly?

First by not using the stilted example of three Uber drivers all driving enormous SUVs 250 miles a day. [Technology Connections has the best advice I've ever seen on this point; please take 5 minutes (from 28:15)](https://youtu.be/Iyp_X3mwE1w?t=1695) and hear Alec. Deeply.

Those people Alec mentioned who slap in one *or even two* 50A circuits are likely to set their panel or house on fire because they have not done a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation, or have to pay for an extremely costly service upgrade **unnecessarily**. As Alec covered, you can amply charge EVs on far less.

"But if I can, why not?" Sure, but have you honestly done that Article 220 Load Calculation?  *Oh. Yeah. I guess I need a $3000 service upgrade.* No you don't!

Now with multiple EVs, you absolutely should leave the travel charger in the trunk (it's for opportunity charging on the road, hence the NEMA 14-50 ***RV*** plug for use at RV parks)... and use hardwired wall units with "Share2" style Power Sharing technology, which allows 2 to 16 EVSEs to share **a single current allocation**.  If one car is charging it gets the works. When a second car plugs in, both get half. A third plugs in, they get 1/3. When one finishes, the other two are back to half.  Etc.

Most makers offer a Share2 style power sharing. Every Tesla Wall Connector since v2 has it built-in.  With v3 it's wireless!

So let's suppose a 50A circuit (250 miles in a 10-hour period) is split among 3 cars.  One car needs 15 miles, one car needs 40 and another needs 180.  **Do they all finish in 10 hours? Yes, they do, with time to spare**.  They share 8 MPH for 2 hours (car #1 finishes), then 12 MPH for 2 hours (car #2 finishes) and then car #3 gets 25 mph for 5.6 more hours.

This can be manipulated by telling less needful cars to delay their charging; right in the car's console.

With only 2 EVs you can do better than that with only 40A circuit (32A to be shared).

Now, how is this *wired*?  Running three home-runs with costly #6 copper is unnecessary. I would use #2 aluminum - nothing wrong with aluminum at these heavy feeder sizes, from the main panel to a subpanel in the garage.  Simply because #2 is the cheapest feeder available.  Why waste money?   Then in the above example I'd have three 50A breakers each feeding an EVSE (just because of NEC/UL rules requiring 1 breaker per EVSE, even though they are sharing the 50A).  Most EVSEs aren't rated for aluminum wire, so you'd need short 2-wire #8 copper (if alone in conduit) or #6 (if shared) for the reasons stated in part 1. The smallest breaker that #2 will fit on is 60A, but it still calculates to 50A in the Load Calculation.  Load Calc permitting, as much as 90A could be shared, since #2 is good to 90A.

All these figures are the commissioning amounts; the EVSE itself will reduce this 20% to provide NEC 625.42 continuous load derate.  Don't apply it again :)

In the uncommon cases where the above is not sufficient, so what? Leave the house with less than full battery, no harm, you won't need it all.  In the *extremely rare* case where all cars arrive at 30% and have a 250 mile day tomorrow all three, then don't come home at 30% - stop at a DC fast charger on the way home for a 15-minute boost from 30-70%. They do that.

Comment: Good examples. In this case it's because the solar company wants to run conductors to the MSP via the subpanel. The subpanel conduit already contains its 100A feeders, so if they want to add solar conductors we need bigger feeders and also bigger solar conductors.

Comment: @Matthew sounds right to me. One option is to derate the feeder. One common error is to use #2 aluminum or #4 copper feeder at 100A. That's only allowed if the service is 100A. (310.15B7) otherwise they are actually 90A or 85A respectively. .  Coincidentally, both are also 100A @ 90°C, so they derate to 80A, which is only a 5-10A downgrade from where they belong.

Comment: "Those people Alec mentioned who slap in one *or even two* 50A circuits are likely to set their panel or house on fire because they have not done a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation" I'd have guessed that that would have just caused the main breaker to start tripping. How would it cause fires?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That bets the farm on the main breaker.  Single point of failure. Not a good plan with the large population of FPE and Zinsco out there. Worse, Rule of Six/split-bus panels are out there in large number, and they have no main breaker at all - they hang it all on the Load Calculation.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that those two stack. They stand alone. I have never done something like that, would have run the 50 amp continuous load in it's own conduit. I did get called in to finish a job the contractors bailed on and they did something similar and it didn't pass inspection because they didn't stack the numbers. I corrected it by running a separate conduit.

Comment: In this case the conduit is 2" sch80 under the slab.